# Is catching a specific exception less expensive than catching a generic one?

Tags: java, android

Say I'm loading a Bitmap onto my Android device. There are many possible exceptions that can be thrown. For the sake of simplicity let's take `NullPointerException` and `OutOfMemoryError`.

Now I have two pieces of code.

**Code 1**

```
try{
//load the bitmap
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//do something
}
```

**Code 2**

```
try{
//load the bitmap
catch (NullPointerException e)
{
//do something
}
catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
{
//do something else
}
```

Is one piece of code more effective than the other **performance** wise? If so, why?

Comment: I don't know if it is more/less effective but catching specific exceptions and handle them appropriately is usually a better practice

Comment: Effective from what perspective? Performance? Readability? Easiness to find bugs later on?

Comment: Performance, of course.

Comment: It is better to avoid exceptions overall.

Comment: @NicolasTyler Why is it better to avoid exceptions overall is my question.

Comment: Exceptions reduce performance.

Comment: you should not catch OutOfMemoryError by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From **byte code point of view** it is more effective (less code) to do the first one.

But you should **NEVER** look at performance in that way.

If you have the same behavior for all type of exceptions, you should use the first bunch of code, in any other way, the second one.

In byte code you have following code responsible for catching eceptions:

```
   L2
    LINENUMBER 7 L2
   FRAME SAME1 java/lang/NullPointerException
    ASTORE 1
    GOTO L4
   L3
    LINENUMBER 9 L3
   FRAME SAME1 java/lang/Exception
    ASTORE 1
   L4
```

So each exceptions has a code that is responsible for catching that, but as I said this is such a minor difference that it shouldn't be taken into consideration.

Comment: Could you substantiate you answer a little? Is the effectiveness from byte code point of view something that can be perceived? Or is it negligible?

Comment: I've added byte code to a post. The only thing is a little more code and a jump in case of `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I never made my point clear enough before, also as Michal said its very minor. But its better to avoid exceptions with `if` statements. Obviously not all exceptions can be avoided but a `NullPointerException` can be foreseen.

Comment: I agree, `NullPointerException` is an error and we should never let it happen!

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise there's no difference as only one catch will be executed even in case of multiple catch blocks.

Code wise, yes first one is better as Michal said. Good practice wise second approach is better as you are able to capture specific exceptions and handle them appropriately.

Side note: don't catch out of memory error ever, its an error not exception and you cant handle it effectively

Answer (score 0):

if you have different behaviours for each exception the second one is better than the first.

The performances will be the same.